# Raster calculator for wind turbine output

Tags: qgis, raster-calculator

Information about the amount of wind energy is available from the global wind atlas (Downloaded from https://globalwindatlas.info/ )  and is available to you as the raster layer Power-density_100m.tif.

The value in the cells of this raster layer is the annual mean power density for wind turbines with a hub height of 100 meters, the unit is W/m2.

For this screening, we are looking at wind turbines with a total height of 150m (hub height = 100m) and a rooter diameter of 117 m. This specification means that the wind turbine approximately can produce `¼ * π * 117 ≈10751` times the value in the cells of the raster layer given in wats.

This is if they were 100 % efficient in converting wind energy to electric energy, the theoretical maximum (Betz limit) is 59.3 %, however, let’s say our wind turbine has an efficiency of 45% it can therefore produce `10751*0.45  = 4838` times the value in the raster layer.

If we also assume that we need a production of 30 Million kWh for the wind turbine to be economically sound that means that we need an annual mean wind density of `30.000.000.000/(365,2*24)/ 4838 ≈ 707 W/m2`.

You, therefore, need to find cells in the Power-density_100m.tif file where the value is larger than 707.

How do I calculate this in a raster calc in QGIS?

Answer (score 2):

Use the expression:

`("SWE_power-density_100m@1">707)*1 + ("SWE_power-density_100m@1"<=707)*0`

(Replace the raster layer name).

It works like an if/else statement:

If `("SWE_power-density_100m@1">707)` is True it equals to 1; so for values above 707: `1 * 1`

For values equal to or below 707: `1 * 0`

[image]